# Grey bar overlaps UI on Chrome Mobile when URL bar resizes on scroll?

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby

I am implementing an app-like bottom navigation bar on the mobile version of my website. I am running into an issue where a grey bar overlaps the bottom navigation bar when scrolling. I think this is due to the window resizing as the URL Bar is scrolled out of view.
[It looks like this when scolling.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgakO.jpg)

Any ideas on how to keep the bottom navigation fixed to the bottom of the window, even as it is resizing due to the URL Bar hiding?

Here is the CSS for the bottom navigation element and each link within the footer:

```
.footer {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: darkgrey;
    background-color: white;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}
.footerLink {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: darkgrey;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    font-size: .9rem;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4.0rem;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And here is the Javascript of the React Element:

```
const BottomNav = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={headerStyles.footer} >
            <Link className={styleFooter('/')}
                to='/'
            >
                <Icon size='large' style={{ margin: '3px' }} name='home' />Home</Link>

            <Link
                className={styleFooter('/exclusive-dining')}
                to='/exclusive-dining'
            >
                <Icon size='large' name='food' />Packages</Link>
            <Link
                className={styleFooter('/happy-hour-finder')}
                to='/happy-hour-finder'
            >
                <Icon size='large' name='glass martini' />
                Happy Hours</Link>
            <Link
                className={styleFooter('/articles')}
                to='/articles'
            >
                <Icon size='large' name='newspaper' />Articles</Link>
            <Link
                className={styleFooter('/app/profile')}
                to='/app/profile'
            >
                <Icon size='large' name='user' />Profile</Link>
        </div >
    )
}

export default BottomNav;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. In my global CSS, I realized that overflow was set to hidden on the html tag, like so:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This was causing the additional screen space to show as blank as the inner window resized. Removing this code fixed the issue.